# How to save my yahoo finance output to excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I am trying to pull this options data in order to do some analysis in excel. I have managed to pull the data from yahoo finance but cannot save it to an excel file. I have tried with the xlsx writer but cannot seem to get it in the right order. Here is my code so far:

```
from yahoo_fin import options
tsla_dates = options.get_expiration_dates("tsla")
print(tsla_dates)
output = options.get_calls("TSLA", "August 21, 2020")
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter("Options.xlsx", engine ='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(output, sheet_name('Sheet1')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      5 import xlsxwriter
      6 datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter("Options.xlsx", engine ='xlsxwriter')
----> 7 data.to_excel(output, sheet_name('Sheet1'))
      8 datatoexcel.save()

NameError: name 'data' is not defined

```
datatoexcel.save()
```

Also do you know how I can save the output from options.get_calls into a data frame?

Thanks A lot

Comment: So, what does the error tell you ? 'data' is not defined. You're calling `data.to_excel.(...)`. What is your `data` object ? (and also, there's still a parenthesis missing at the end)

Comment: Can you comment everything following ```output = options.get_calls("TSLA", "August 21, 2020")``` and show us what you get ?